# Fill background by tiling with bitmap

Tags: delphi, background, delphi-xe2, firemonkey, window-resize

In my FMX Application I have to fill the entire background area of my form using a Bitmap pattern. 
The reason why I'm thinking to use this pattern is because the form is freely resizable by the user and whether I set a fixed image the stretch causes the loss of quality of the background.

Is there a way to use a small Bitmap pattern I can repeat (X and Y) to fill the whole form area according to the resizing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The effect you are looking for is a `Tile`.

See [`TTilerEffect`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Filter.Effects.TTilerEffect) and [`FireMonkey_Image_Effects`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/FireMonkey_Image_Effects) for documentation.

The properties `HorizontalTileCount` and `VerticalTileCount` controls how many times a bitmap will be replicated. Since these values are floats, you need to adapt their values when the form is rescaled.

Answer (score 2):

- Add a TImage to the form
- Make all the other controls children of it (so they appear on top).
- Set the image's Align to alClient.
- Load the Bitmap.
- Set the WrapMode to imTile.